# Finding between zodiac by only date and month

Tags: php

I'm quite frustrated with the following code, which should show the Zodiac sign of a baby by using only date and month.

```
$babyDue= date('d-m',strtotime("23-04-2015"));

$ariesStart=date('d-m',strtotime("21-03-2016")); 
$ariesEnd=date('d-m',strtotime("20-04-2016")); 

$taurusStart=date('d-m',strtotime("21-04-2016"));
$taurusEnd=date('d-m',strtotime("20-05-2016"));

$zodiac="thisTextNeedToChange"; 

if(($babyDue>$ariesStart) && ($babyDue<$ariesEnd)) {
    //Set $zodiac to aries
    $zodiac="aries";
    echo $zodiac; 
} elseif (($babyDue>$taurusStart)&& ($babyDue<$taurusEnd)){
    //Set $zodiac to Taurus
    $zodiac="Taurus";
    echo $zodiac; 
}
```

I think my logic is correct, but it's not showing anything :(

Comment: you need to compare unix timestamps alone, don't compare the strings

Comment: You can't determine the astrological sign by month only. As evident from your own example, April babies can be either Aries or Taurus. You have to use the full birth date.

Comment: http://www.internoetics.com/2014/03/03/find-a-zodiac-sign-by-birthdate-with-php/ - you're welcome.

Comment: So which mean i have to take "day" and put it in a variable
follow by take month and put it in the variable . 
and Compare ... am i right ?

Comment: Maybe you can do simple logic like this http://coursesweb.net/php-mysql/zodiac-signs_cs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$babyBirthDate = new DateTime('23 April');

$zodiacs = array(
    'Aries' => array(
         new DateTime('21 March'),
         new DateTime('20 April'),
    ),
    'Taurus' => array(
         new DateTime('21 April'),
         new DateTime('20 May'),
    )
);

foreach ($zodiacs as $zodiac => $dateTimeRange) {
    if ($babyBirthDate >= $dateTimeRange[0] && $babyBirthDate <= $dateTimeRange[1]) {
        echo $zodiac;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is way too simple because accurate zodiac calculations involve astronomy.